# Org: including clock-out timestamp in clock table report

Tags: org-mode, org-clock, org-clock-table

I'd like to have a clock table report include the date in which each task was completed. Is it possible to have a column for the last clock-out date? Using `:timestamp t` only works for the scheduled or deadline timestamp...

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure what exactly you want: (a) the date the task was completed or (b) the last clock-out date. These are not necessarily the same. I have no solution for (b), but can provide one for (a):

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :properties ("CLOSED")
#+END:
```

The `CLOSED` property is one of a few [special properties](http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-properties.html#Special-properties) which is available with the `:properties` option. (For other options check [this page](http://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html).)

Comment: This works. I had to set `(setq org-log-done 'time)` to have a CLOSED timestamp inserted when I change TODO status to DONE. So in my file this will only work for reports with future tasks... But anyway, thanks!